# Como puedo desactivar una funcion en python mediante un temporizador

Tags: python

Necesito poner algun tipo de temporizador a esta funcion, es decir que a los 30 segudos por ejemplo se desactive.

```
def On_Command(self, Player, cmd, args):
    if cmd == "a":
        if self.Enable == 1:
            if Player.Admin:
                if len(args) == 0:
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, green + "---------- AdminTool by: [color green]Pompeyo[/color] [color aqua]Version:[/color] [color yellow]1.0[/color] ----------")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a - para ver los comandos")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a owner - entrar en el modo propietario escribe /a owner de nuevo para deshabilitarlo")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a tp <Name>")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a bring <Name> - trae al jugador a ti")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a return - te trae de vuelta a tu última ubicación")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a kit - Recibe un kit")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a invis - Te da un traje invisible")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a invisoff - Elimina el traje invisible")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a casper - Entrar en modo fantasma")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a casperoff - Regresar a la normalidad humana")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a door - Habilitar  admin doors")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a dooroff - Inhabilitar admin doors")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a remove - Activa el modo remove")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a removeoff - Inhabilitar el modo remove")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a stp - te teletransporta a la entidad que golpeas")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a hp <Name>- Compruebe la salud de alguien")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a savepoint - Salvar el punto donde estás parado")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a usepoint - tp al punto guardado")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a gameid <Name> - Muestra su ID")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a ipad <Name> - Muestra su Ip")
                      Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "/a time <Name> - Vea cuánto tiempo alguien está jugando en t")
                      return
                else:
                    arg = args[0]
                    elif arg == "remove":
                        if Player.Admin or Player.Moderator:
                            DataStore.Add("ARemove", Player.SteamID, "ARemover")
                            Player.MessageFrom(sysname, yellow + "Modo remove habilitado, golpea un objeto para eliminarlo")
                            Plugin.Log("Remover", Player.Name + " ha usado el comando remove")
                            return
```

Donde necesito poner el temporizador es en el remove

Comment: No proporcionas información de contexto. ¿Es ese código parte de algún servidor? ¿En qué framework está desarrollado? La forma en que se crea un temporizador es diferente si estás en un framework multihilo, o uno asíncrono, u orientado a eventos. En todo caso, lo que puede ser más general es el cómo desactivar la función una vez el contador expire. Puedes hacer que la función consulte una variable (ej: `expirado`) y si es `True` retorne sin hacer nada. El temporizador al expirar pondrá esa variable a `True`.

Comment: hola amigo !! este codigo es parte de un plugin de un servidor de juego (Rust), no conosco casi nada de python asi q no puedo brindar mucha informacion, lo que si pudiera hacer es poner el codigo completo del plugin

Comment: Realmente no lo puse completo antes para que no fuera tan extenso, saludos y gracias de antemano por la ayuda!!!

Comment: Sí, no tiene sentido poner un código completo, pero sí dar más contexto sobre el entorno de ejecución de ese código, aunque sea un enlace al juego, la documentación del plugin, etc. Si quieres puedes subir el código completo a algún pastebin y poner el enlace en un comentario, a ver si puedo echarle un ojo